# How to remove bottom border of the last row of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, border, wpfdatagrid

As you can see the bottom border of the last row in data grid falls near the border of the data grid and makes it look ugly. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DevLengths}"  
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length of Splice" Binding="{Binding LengthOfSplice}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length of Development" Binding="{Binding LengthOfDevelopment}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ldh" Binding="{Binding Ldh}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length of Hook" Binding="{Binding LengthOfHook}" Width="*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-1,0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"` for your `DataGrid`. This will remove the bottom border and set the the top, left, right to the default of 1.

So your new code would be:

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DevLengths}"  
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length of Splice" Binding="{Binding LengthOfSplice}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length of Development" Binding="{Binding LengthOfDevelopment}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ldh" Binding="{Binding Ldh}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length of Hook" Binding="{Binding LengthOfHook}" Width="*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-1,0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Any idea how to remove all the row borders?

Comment: You can set `GridLinesVisibility` (another `DataGrid` property) to `All`, `Horizontal`, `None` or `Vertical` depending which parts you want to hide.